# How to download Azure BLOB?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am not able to download azure blob file to my local disk. Please find below the java code I am using to download the file. When I run and do a HTTP trigger test, I do not see the file downloaded into my Local path. Also, I have given the authentication as public access.And , I am able to read the contents of the txt file using the blob.downloadText(). But I am not able to download it to a file.

My requirement is to download a pdf in the Blob Storage to my Local Disk.

```
 @FunctionName("BlobDownload-Java")
    public void run1(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");


        try {
            // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

            // Get a reference to a container.
            // The container name must be lower case
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("doccontainer");


          CloudBlockBlob blob1 = container.getBlockBlobReference("AssembledDoc.pdf");

          context.getLogger().info("File Name Check 1 ----->" +  blob1.getName()); 


          CloudBlockBlob blob2 = container.getBlockBlobReference("Test.txt");
          String s= blob2.downloadText();
          context.getLogger().info("Text Document content ----->" + s );
          File file = new File("C:\\Users\\wb541348\\Project\\Temp.txt");
          blob2.downloadToFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to download PDF file to local, here is my test code , you could have a try.

```
@Test
public void downloadBlob(){


    try {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

        //Create the service client object for credentialed access to the Blob service.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("blobcontainer");


        CloudBlob blob1 =container.getBlockBlobReference("thinking-in-java.pdf");

        blob1.download(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\georgec\\Documents\\" + blob1.getName()));


    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}
```

If you still have questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

@Prasanna, Your can't download the blob into your localpath because the pattern of your path is wrong, it should be "c:/Users/wb541348/Project/Temp.txt", there is another point to pay attention, that is the filename is needed, which means that path shouldn't be only folder, hope it benefits.
you can also click this [sample of azure blob for java sdk](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-java-getting-started/blob/master/src/BlobBasics.java) for reference.