# How to send pdf response from a Azure Function java?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

Can someone let me know how to send pdf response from a HTTP Trigger Azure function in Java.

Once the function is triggered, I need to read a pdf from Azure storage and return the pdf as response to the browser.

Comment: `return the pdf as response to the browser`, do you want to download or display it in the browser? Is your [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600091/how-to-download-azure-blob) identical to this one? If not, please let us know what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @Jerry Liu : I want to send them as response and download in browser. Please give me the azure function code. Yes , it is related to the previous post. My azure function should take the pdf file from azure storage and the send the response as pdf to the browser and download it in the browser

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
package com.function;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;

import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.*;

public class HttpTriggerJava {
    @FunctionName("HttpTriggerJava")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = { HttpMethod.GET,
            HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        try {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(
                    "{your storage connections tring}");
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("{container name}");
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("{filename}");

            byte[] content = new byte[blob.getStreamWriteSizeInBytes()];
            blob.downloadToByteArray(content, 0);

            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(content)
                .build();

        } catch (InvalidKeyException | URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                .body(e.getMessage())
                .build();
        } catch (StorageException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .body(e.getMessage())
                .build();
        }   
    }
}
```